# Is there a way to get all the features and their booleans from Azure App Configuration?

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-app-configuration

Using [IFeatureManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.featuremanagement.ifeaturemanager?view=azure-dotnet-preview) only has two methods that only allow to get a feature per request. Is there a way to get all the features and their values (true or false)?

Answer (score 3):

@Elias Rodriguez, you can call `FeatureManager.GetFeatureNamesAsync()` to get the full list of feature flags that are available. Then you can call `FeatureManager.IsEnabledAsync()` on each of them to get their true/false status.

Comment: So, if I have 40 features I would be doing 40 calls right?

Comment: You do one call to `GetFeatureNamesAsync` to get all feature flag names and do 40 calls to `IsEnabledAsync` to get their true/false status. Note that the feature flag state is evaluated locally to your app when calling `IsEnabledAsync`. There are no network calls to App Configuration during that process.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AppConfiguration stores all of its data in the Configuration subsystem (Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration). [More on this topic here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

You can peek inside all of the configuration by registering `IConfigurationRoot` into DI and injecting it in a service and calling its `GetDebugView()` *. This method was added in .NET Core 3.0, so if you are in an older version you will not have it. You can always just loop over the `IConfigurationRoot` and take a look at its content.

Once you have identified the `key` that you are interested in, you can just use `configurationRoot[Key]` to extract the raw data from Azure AppConfiguration.

Comment: If I understood correctly, this only gets them all once at the startup of the application and never again until the app is restarted. Is there a way to get all the updated configurations from Azure App Configuration every time it is needed?

Comment: [Based on the documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/FeatureManagement-Dotnet#caching) they should get refreshed if you do a `IConfigurationRoot.Reload()`